# How to call a global npm command in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor, npm, command-line-interface

**Background**

Meteor is shipped with a packaged npm. Calling any npm related commands requires the following pattern:

```
meteor npm [command]
```

I installed a global npm package ([npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing)):

```
meteor npm install -g npm-install-missing
```

**Problem**

It is intended to be called as a toplevel command:

> Usage
>
> Within your project directory:
>
> npm-install-missing The script will check the current project
>   directory for missing dependencies and install them automatically.

So I tried inside my project dir the some possible variations of calling it:

**1. meteor npm-install-missing**

Obviously as calling npm via meteor using the meteor command in before. Turned out to be wrong:

```
> meteor npm-install-missing

> 'npm-install-missing' is not a Meteor command. See 'meteor --help'.
```

**2. npm-install-missing (without meteor command)**

Ok, so maybe it is top-level installed and I can call it like so. Turned out to be wrong, too.

```
> npm-install-missing
> npm-install-missing is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

**3. meteor npm run npm-install-missing**

Obviously wrong, because I have no script in my package.json but I gave it a try anyway. Turned out to be wrong:

```
> meteor npm run npm-install-missing
> npm ERR! missing script: npm-install-missing
```

**Question**

How can I call this package without additionally installing nodejs and npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay turned out to be too easy, but for documentation purposes I want to share my result.

Just install global commands (such as in my case npm-install-missing) also with the `--save` option.

```
meteor npm install -g --save npm-install-missing
```

Then you can call it globally in any of your meteor projects like npm itself:

```
meteor npm-install-missing
```

**Background**

Without the `--save` option, it would be installed in the npm-cache subdir of meteor's Roaming AppData but not linked to the bin folder of the meteor tool. This is the folder where meteor looks for these global commands to be called.

The folder is in windows:

```
AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node_modules
```

Without `--save` it hasn't been installed there.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the solution! I hadn't tried `meteor <package-command>` but just `<package-command>` and thought I cannot use global npm packages with Meteor but I can actually!